# Hash function to return only positive number from integer

Tags: hash, hashing

What would be a good hash function that will return a positive integer value, even if the key is an negative integer value? How do I pick a hash function? So what I would want is to associate negative numbers with some positive value so I can use them later.

UPDATE: (summary)
I need to find a bijection $f: \mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{N}$ which also has the property that:
$$
f(x) + f(y) = f(x + y)
$$

Comment: What is the purpose of your hash function?

Comment: @reinierpost the purpose is to map negative numbers to some positive value and also not collide with other positive numbers from an array. so basically, I have an array with some integer values, and i want to map every integer value from that array to some other positive value so then i could use an algorithm that only works for positive values.

Comment: In that case, any simple bijection from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ will do, right? It doesn't need to "hash" (mix up the ordering).

Comment: @reinierpost sure, but i cant think of any bijection like that

Comment: @reinerpost nevermind, i think i found one! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, it appears all you need a bijection from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ that is easy to compute.

The simplest one I can think of: $x \mapsto 1/2 + 2 \mid\!(x - 1/4)\mid$.

This isn't really a hash function: it doesn't "hash" (scatter its consecutive function values across their range).

Comment: Hello, I also need that the function to be like f(x) + f(y) = f(x + y)

Comment: Can you see the edit?

Comment: Yes. With that additional requirement, no such function exists: for infinitely many different $x$, you now require that $f(x)$ is positive, $f(-x)$ is positive, and $f(x) + f(-x) = f(0)$; no value for $f(0)$ can meet that requirement.. Are you sure you really need it? Or perhaps your function doesn't need to be injective?

Comment: @reinerpost The problem goes like this: given an array with N integer elements find the longest subsequence which sum gives K.  and i thought of a linear time solution but only works for positive elements, so that's why i'm searching for something like this

Comment: Perhaps you can now derive that your approach doesn't work ...

Comment: then, what approach should I use?

Comment: That's a different question ...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: map the positive numbers to the odd numbers and the negative numbers to the even numbers.